# Simple Javascript Execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

this should be fairly simple for those of you who understand jQuery.

I am trying to get this script to run ONLY if `<span class="site-header__cart-indicator "></span>` is present on the loaded page.

Here is the untouched jQuery code:

```js
window.setTimeout(redirectCheckout, 2000);

function redirectCheckout() {
  if (!(window.location.href.includes("?1"))) {
    window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/checkout";
  }
}
```

So here is my version of the code but it doesn't seem to be working:

```js
if (!(window.location.includes("<span class="
    site - header__cart - indicator "></span>")))
  window.setTimeout(redirectCheckout, 2000);

function redirectCheckout() {
  if (!(window.location.href.includes("?1"))) {
    window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/checkout";
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why my code isn't working? What would be the correct code?

Comment: There is no jQuery code in here!

Answer (score 2):

To check if an element exists in the page you can select it then check the `length` property (if using jQuery) or if it's null (if using plain JS):

```
// jQuery
if ($('.site-header__cart-indicator').length)
  window.setTimeout(redirectCheckout, 2000);

// plain JS
if (window.querySelector('.site-header__cart-indicator'))
  window.setTimeout(redirectCheckout, 2000);
```

Comment: Was just adding the POJS version :)

Comment: You realize even if you're using jQuery, it's still plain old JavaScript, right? :-) The difference is whether you're using jQuery or the DOM, nothing to do with what *language* you're writing...

Comment: Of course, I mean 'plain JS' in the sense that there's no framework involved.

Comment: Next time, please close the question as the obvious duplicate it is, instead of answering yet another copy of this concept.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing you have a quoting error:

```
"<span class="site-header__cart-indicator"></span>"
```

should be:

```
'<span class="site-header__cart-indicator"></span>'
```

**But more to the point**, this condition makes no sense.  That string would never be in the *location* (the current URL).  It would be *on the page*.

Even though your code currently has no jQuery, you do specifically request its use.  In which case you can select for that element and see if there are any matches.  Something like this:

```
if ($('span.site-header__cart-indicator').length > 0)
```

Comment: Next time, please close the question as the obvious duplicate it is, instead of answering yet another copy of this concept.